# how to disable lwuit vkb?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, midlet, virtual-keyboard

The ability for disabling vkb is included in the new svn source code...
But by default vkb comes in midlet...
How to disable it in midlet...
In the old documentation it was given

> To use the LWUIT Virtual keyboard an application must call:
>   VKBImplementationFactory.init(); 
> before calling to:
>   Display.init(this);

but in the latest version VKBImplementationFactory is deprecated .
And old documentation it was given to enable only...there was no details about disabling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Display.setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(null);`

Comment: You should probably open new questions for these I would try VirtualKeyboard.bindVirtualKeyboard() not sure if it would work for this?

Comment: Display.setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(null)  didnt work but Display.getInstance().setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(null) did....after disabling vkb ...and i tested on a nokia touch screen mobile...the mobiles vkb is not showing up

Answer (score 0):

```
Display.getInstance().setDefaultVirtualKeyboard(null)
```

This will cause that VKB disabled but the problem is on touch devices which then you do not have any keyboard/